# Duration_in_traffic less than duration in google Distance Matrix API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-distancematrix-api

I am using both the "duration_in_traffic" and "duration" feature using the DistanceMatrix API.

For a given coordinate pair, I see the following results:

```
{
  "destination_addresses": [
    "Hamburg, Germany"
  ],
  "origin_addresses": [
    "85748 Garching, Germany"
  ],
  "rows": [
    {
      "elements": [
        {
          "distance": {
            "text": "761 km",
            "value": 760831
          },
          "duration": {
            "text": "7 hours 1 min",
            "value": 25242
          },
          "duration_in_traffic": {
            "text": "6 hours 42 mins",
            "value": 24145
          },
          "status": "OK"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "status": "OK"
}
```

Here is my question:

**How is it that the duration_in_traffic is less than duration?**

From what i understood:

Duration: Duration of travel on a route... Not sure if it is without traffic

Duration_in_traffic: Duration of travel on a route under traffic conditions.

Any explanation on this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: From what I observed, it happens when you specify a departure time earlier than now.

Comment: It depends on the day/time at which you request duration in traffic.

Answer (score 11):

> Note: The durationInTraffic field is now deprecated. It was previously
>   the recommended way for Google Maps API for Work customers to specify
>   whether the result should include a duration that takes into account
>   current traffic conditions. You should now use the drivingOptions
>   field instead.

**Duration** seems to take an average of durations at different times/from historic data, while **duration_in_traffic** takes the given departure time (and live traffic) into account. So the route takes *7 hours 1 min* in average, but with your given time it only takes you *6 hours 42 mins* from Hamburg to Garching.

I don't know if Google has that detailed data, but it could be that during the day a part of the highway is most of the times limited to 60 km/h because of dense traffic, while your travel time is around 23:00 and due to that you are allowed to drive 120 km/h.

There are also the three values for [`traffic_model`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro?hl=de#traffic-model): best_guess, pessimistic and optimistic which can influence the `duration_in_traffic` value.

Comment: `durationInTraffic` was a request parameter, not a response field.  Its deprecation has no bearing on this question.